# jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin') - When do I need this when making plugin?

Tags: plugin

To be honest, I don't know what `jimport` and `jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin')` do.  So I think an explanation of what they do might as well answer my question.

That being said, I've made a simple plugin without `jimport('joomla.plugin.plugin')`, but in other plugins I see this a lot, so when do I need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that specific instance is a relic of the past. It was used to import the base class that your plugin class extended. (eg the `JPlugin` in `class PlgUserJoomla extends JPlugin`
)

The `joomla.plugin.plugin` was a representation for the file in the libraries folder `JPATH_ROOT . "/libraries/joomla/plugin/plugin.php"` if I remember right.

`jimport('xxx')` is currently an alias for `JLoader::import('xxx')` and still used for some imports in the Joomla source.

```
function jimport($path, $base = null)
{
    return JLoader::import($path, $base);
}
```

However, the necessity of that I am unsure of. Much of the source auto-loads now either via a namespace or or an alias.

For example, `JPlugin` is an alias of `\Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin`.

```
JLoader::registerAlias('JPlugin',                           '\\Joomla\\CMS\\Plugin\\CMSPlugin', '5.0');
```

---

Note: As of right now, current version of Joomla is 3.9.13.

Comment: An additional note just to make it sure: there is no need of using `jimport();` function in plugins anymore, since the JPlugin class is autoloaded.

Comment: However I would always use the namespaced version now as it is in your answer. So, on the top of a plugin class file: `use \Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;` and extend `CMSPlugin` with the plugin.

Comment: @Zollie Is `use \Joomla\CMS\Plugin\CMSPlugin;` necessary? My plugin runs well without it

Comment: @shenkwen - no, you do not have to use that if you extend the `JPlugin` aliased class without referencing it using `CMSPlugin` namespace (only few years later will have real relevance of using the `CMSPlugin` namespaced name instead of `JPlugin` when you create a plugin, As far as I remember only in Joomla 5.